# What is the best practices place to manipulate form data before saving in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

From the pointview of rails best practices, what is the best place to manipulate form data before saving?

For instace, on a contact form, I want to make sure that all data is saved in capitalized form  ( don't you hate when PEOPLE SHOUT AT YOU in their "please contact me" form submission? :-) )

- is it better to do manipulation in controller? I could either do it in create, or move it into some sort of private method , that will capitalize all string attributes of the object before saving / updating?

**Or**

- is it better do in the model before_save?
  It makes sense to me that it should be done in the model since I probably want that to be the same for all records, no matter whether I manipulate on them in a rake task or through the web interface.

**Bonus:**

Also where would I place it if I want that that on ALL my models, with the ability to override default on a case by case basis? Application controller?
There might be some special cases where you want to save value without capitalizing - i.e. brand name products that don't capitalize (i.e. utorrent) or a last name that should have multiple caps in the name (i.e. Irish & Scottish names like McDonald)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok based on the suggestions from other replies I came up with this solution:

**lib/clean_strings.rb**

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    attr_accessor :dont_capitlize, :dont_strip

    before_save :_capitalize_strings, :unless => :dont_capitlize
    before_save :_strip_whitespaces,  :unless => :dont_strip

    def _capitalize_strings
      self.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
        self[key] = value.capitalize if value.respond_to?('capitalize')
      end
    end


    def _strip_whitespaces
      self.attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
        self[key] = value.strip if value.respond_to?('strip')
      end
    end

  end
end
```

in **environment.rb** addded

```
require "clean_strings"
```

Now whenever I do

```
@a.dont_capitalize = true
@a.save!
```

it cleans it before saving according to my rules ( it will strip whitespace, but not capitalize it ). Obviously it needs more fine tuning, but i think it's a good way to define format rules for  commonplace things. This way I don't need to sanitize every and each form input for things like extra whitespaces, or people who don't know where the CAPS LOCK is !!!

Thank you all for your input ( all upvoted).

Answer (score 4):

the easiest place to put this is in your model.  I would suggest using either before_save or even before_validation if you feel that fits better.  Something like this would do the trick:

```
before_save :upcase_content

def upcase_content
  self.content = self.content.upcase
end
```

Additionally if you wanted to allow for exceptions of a case by case basis you could add an attr_accessor to your model.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :dont_upcase

before_save :upcase_content, :unless => :dont_upcase
...
end
```

then when you create a model set the accessor to true

```
@model = Model.new(:brand_name => utorrent)
@model.dont_upcase = true
@model.save!
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea about accessors - I'll need to check it further.

Comment: yea its something i picked up on through a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations) - a little dated now but the theory behind it remains the same

Answer (score 3):

The best place to put this is in your model, that way you have a fat model and a skinny controller, which is a "good thing".

If you want to have this be available for all of your models my suggestion is to use a module which contains your shared functionality and then include that in all the models you want to have the default behavior.

Comment: I don't wont to have to include it in every model, I'd rather overwrite it in those that I don't need it ( I have  over 70 models, that should all have certain field formated in this way, and only a few that should no have this behavior) I think I'll just extend active record in lib. But thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Another alternative is to have a base class you inherit from everywhere. I'd recommend not patching in an initializer.

Comment: see my own answer - that's what I ended up doing.